# How do I collapse on a specific pattern in a text?

Tags: r

I have some strings of text (example below). As you can see each string was split at a period or question mark.

```
   [1]"I am a Mr."
   [2]"asking for help."
   [3]"Can you help?"
   [4]"Thank you ms."
   [5]"or mr."
```

I want to collapse where the string ends with an abbreviation like mr., mrs. so the end result would be the desired output below.

```
    [1]"I am a Mr. asking for help."
    [2]"Can you help?"
    [3]"Thank you ms. or mr."
```

I already created a vector (called abbr) containing all my abbreviations in the following format:

```
> abbr
[1] "Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Ave|Blvd|Rd|Mt|Capt|Maj"
```

but I can't figure out how to use it in paste function to collapse. I have also tried using gsub (didn't work) to replace \n following abbreviation with a period with a space like this:

`lines<-gsub('(?<=abbr\\.\\n)(?=[A-Z])', ' ', lines, perl=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tapply` to collapse string and `grepl` to create groups to collapse.

```
x <- c("I am a Mr.", "asking for help.","Can you help?","Thank you ms.", "or Mr.")
#Include all the abbreviations with proper cases
#Note that "." has a special meaning in regex so you need to escape it. 
abbr <- 'Mr\\.|Mrs\\.|Ms\\.|Dr\\.|mr\\.|ms\\.'

unname(tapply(x, c(0, head(cumsum(!grepl(abbr, x)), -1)), paste, collapse = " "))
#[1] "I am a Mr. asking for help." "Can you help?"  "Thank you ms. or mr."
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this code worked with most of the strings in the text i used but it also ended up mistakenly collapsing a few of the strings that had no abbreviation and ended with a normal period.

Comment: If it makes a diff. my abbr vector contained abbreviations without the periods but i have to keep them in that format.

Comment: @Davraham So for those abbreviations which don't end in periods don't use `\\.` for them in `abbr`. If it still doesn't work can you share an example of where it fails?

Comment: Here is an example(before it was split after the period): on line [993] "This business at Coburg Square is serious. “Why serious?"

Comment: Do you have `us\\.` in `abbr`? Probably you need to add word boundaries to every abbreviation like this. `abbr <- '\\bMr\\.\\b|\\bMrs\\.\\b|\\bMs\\.\\b|\\bDr\\.\\b|\\bmr\\.\\b|\\bms\\.\\b'
`